# How do I sort folders by comment in Mac using AppleScripts?

Tags: macos, mac, sorting, applescript, comments

I have folders in this order:

```
content  
forms 
gallery  
header  
misc
navigation
slider
title
```

I want to sort them this way:

```
navigation
header
content
title
gallery
slider
forms
misc
```

I have seen some AppleScripts sorting by comments. Couldn't figure out how to do this as I don't know AppleScripts.

Could you please help?

Comment: Does it have to be by Applescript? Would it not be simpler to just click on the Comments column?

Comment: the thing is, it works only on finders. I need  it to work if I open that folder in any code editor like vscode, atom or icecoder.

Comment: File-picker dialogs can be sorted the same way as Finder windows.